# count new user and returning user with time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, clickhouse, apache-superset

I got a dataset like this:

[image]

I want to count new and returning users with different time ranges, but there are duplicates of *user_id* in returning. For example:
I got a data like this:

[image]

with a time range from 15/12/2021 to 20/12/2021,

the output: 2 new users, 2 returning users.

I use SQL clickhouse and superset for visualizing.

My coding attempt:

```
WITH data AS ( 
    SELECT user_id, 
           created_time, 
           MIN(created_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS first_time, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS no_login 
    FROM default.active_user
), data2 AS ( 
    SELECT *, 
          (CASE WHEN no_login=1 THEN 'new' ELSE 'returning' END) AS category_user 
    FROM data
) 
SELECT user_id, 
       COUNT(distinct user_id) AS active_user, 
       category_user,
       created_time 
FROM data2 
GROUP BY user_id, 
         category_user, 
         created_time
```

Comment: can you show your latest coding attempt to this problem?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: with data as(
select 
  user_id,
  created_time,
  min(created_time) over (partition by user_id) as first_time,
  row_number() over (partition by user_id) as no_login
from 
  default.active_user),
data2 as(
select 
  *,
  (case when no_login=1 then 'new' else 'returning' end) as category_user
from 
data)
select 
  user_id,
  count(distinct user_id) as active_user,
  category_user,created_time 
from 
  data2
group by 
  user_id,
  category_user,
  created_time

Comment: [minimal example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think that all you need is to remove the user_id from the select and the group by, but it is hard to tell for sure without any further information.